# C BitWise - What does "1 << (num - 1)" and "|=" do?

Tags: c, hex, bit-shift

Can you tell me what convertLedNumberToBit and LedDriver_TurnOn do?  I do not understand what is happening with `1 << (num - 1)` and `|=`

```
static uint16_t * ledsAddress;

static uint16_t convertLedNumberToBit(int ledNumber)
{
    return  1 << (ledNumber - 1);
}
void LedDriver_TurnOn(int ledNumber)
{
    *ledsAddress |= convertLedNumberToBit(ledNumber);
}
```

Comment: Better code avoids working with signed integer math and bits.  Suggest  `return  1u << (ledNumber - 1);`  (add u)

Comment: @chux In this scenario, what issue would one have if they left out the u?

Comment: On a 16-bit processor, common in 2016 with embedded processors, `1 << 15` is undefined behavior  See C11 §6.5.7 4.  With  `1u << 15`, it is well defined and functions as expected.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your comment. You should post an answer too with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch 'ON' the LED[ledNumber]  at I/O port `ledsAddress`, it is necessary to set the equivalent bit to '1'. But, when changing the I/O port value, you have to keep the state of all others LED still 'ON'.

The `convertLedNumberToBit(int ledNumber)` is using a mask `b0000000000000001` (16bits) to set the ledNumber bit to '1' by switching to left of (ledNumber-1) { no shift needed when ledNumber is 1.

Ex: (ledNumber = 4) => returned value is `b0000000000001000`= `0x0008`.

Then the call `|= convertLedNumberToBit(ledNumber)` will force only the ledNumber bit to '1' without changing others by a binary-OR.

Ex: (led1, led3 & led7 are 'ON') 
before the OR `b0000000001000101` = `0x0045`.
LedDriver_TurnOn(4) => `b0000000000001000`= `0x0008`
after the OR `b0000000001001101` = `0x004D`.

> To switch 'OFF' the same LED, you have just to replace the OR function by the AND function of the NOT mask.

```
void LedDriver_TurnOff(int ledNumber)
{
    *ledsAddress &= ~(convertLedNumberToBit(ledNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`<<` is a bitwise shift to the left.  A `uint16_t` of `1` in binary is `0b0000000000000001`, so when you shift left by the quantity `ledNumber-1`, the result is a `uint16_t` with a single-bit set to the position specified by `ledNumber`.

From the variable name `ledNumber`, I'm guessing that this function sets a specific LED to work on.

`|` performs a bitwise OR on the two operands it is passed.

For example,

```
byte b = 0x0A | 0x50;
```

If you look at the underlying bits for `0x0A` and `0x50`, they are `0b00001010` and `0b01010000` respectively.  When combined with the OR operator the result in `b` is `0b01011010`, or `0x5A` in hexadecimal.

`|=` is a bitwise OR assignment.  `|=` is analogous to operators like `+=` and `-=` in that it will perform a bitwise OR on the two operands then store the result in the left operator.

```
byte b = 0x0A;
b |= 0x50;

// after this b = 0x5A
```

Comment: Detail on "so when you shift left by the quantity ledNumber-1, the result is a uint16_t".  The `uint16_t` is first promoted to `int` or `unsigned` and then shifted.  So the result may differ in type and sign-ness than `uint16_t`. IAC, OP's code starts with an `int`, shifts and then converts  to `uint16_t`.  A problem exists if a 1 bit was shifted into the sign position.

Comment: @chux so if 17 is passed to the function, the signed bit would be populated?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy Shifting a one into the sign bit of an `int` is undefined behavior.  Shifting into the sign bit of a `uint16_t` is not possible as it does not have a sign bit so `convertLedNumberToBit()` never returns with its non-existent sign bit set.

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference - Arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators) to the rescue

> The bitwise shift operator expressions have the form
>   lhs << rhs  (1)
>   lhs >> rhs  (2)
>   1) left shift of lhs by rhs bits
>   2) right shift of lhs by rhs bits

So `1 << (ledNumber - 1)` shifts the least significant bit to the left, e.g. if `ledNumber = 5`

```
0x0001 << (5 - 1)
```

will become

```
0x0010
```

---

Also [cppreference - Assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment)

`|=` is a (bitwise OR) assignment operator, where

```
*ledsAddress |= convertLedNumberToBit(ledNumber);
```

is equivalent to

```
*ledsAddress = *ledsAddress | convertLedNumberToBit(ledNumber);
```

Comment: is your example not incorrect?  Will the result not be 0x10000

Comment: 5 - 1 = 4, 0x0001 << 4 shifts the zeroth bit 4 bits to the left. One hex digit represents 4 bits, so 0x0001 << 4 = 0x0010.